# Draw image with animation

Tags: objective-c, ios7, cocos2d-iphone, core-graphics, quartz-core

Suppose there is an alphabet i.e. A  and I need to make the image from one point to another. I don't know much about core graphics or quartz concept. Please suggest me that what would be the best way to draw the image at a particular path.[Character animation](http://www.4shared.com/video/2BJzsjTmce/IMG_3135.html)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: nice to see you here :)   Alphabet A and image from one point to another, question is not clear. can u plz explain

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Dear Please check this animation http://www.4shared.com/video/2BJzsjTmce/IMG_3135.html

Comment: @Sudha I am not sure whether it'll help you or not, but still please check it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846413/how-do-you-draw-a-line-programmatically-from-a-view-controller and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856354/how-do-i-draw-a-line-on-the-iphone