# iOS How to implement Matching scenario

Tags: ios, swift

In my iOS Application i have to match the elements like below image , How to draw the line between selected views. What kind of guesstures i have to use.
 Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
let line_path:CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
line_path.move(to: CGPoint(x:x1, y:y1))
line_path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:x2, y:y2))
```

Comment: What you have tried so far

Comment: Are you planning on adding the ability to drag from one image to another to draw the line? Or simply draw the line if button tapped on the left column matches with the button tapped on the right column?

Comment: @pkc456  I am using textview and buttons. Here textview contains ocr resultant text and buttons are name, address... So I want to match them to identify them in easy way by  drag from one textview to another button to draw the line.

Comment: How can I draw path between textview and a button in swift

Comment: I think this link will help u. [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569051/how-to-draw-a-line-in-the-simplest-way-in-swift)

Comment: @SujathaGirijala Have you tried that link?

Comment: yes. Its working for straight lines not for curved

Comment: Will you able to draw line between two components by draging? If yes kindly update your answer here so that i can verify