# Drawing a line in Swift 3.x with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, drawing

I am trying to draw a line on an UIView with an UIBezierpath. I think I am missing something, but wasn't able to find it out.

Here is my code:

```
// Code for touch recognition
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = false
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch? {
        lastPoint = (touch?.location(in: fullview))!
        //print(lastPoint)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = true
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch? {
        let currentPoint = touch?.location(in: fullview)
        drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint!)

        lastPoint = currentPoint!
        //print(lastPoint)
        //print("touch moved")
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if !swiped {
        drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
    }
    //print("touch ended")
}

//code for drawing
func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint){

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(fullview.frame.size)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    let aPath = UIBezierPath()

    //aPath.move(to: fromPoint)
    //aPath.addLine(to: toPoint)
    aPath.lineWidth=10.0
    aPath.lineJoinStyle = .round
    aPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:15,y:15))
    aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:80,y:80))
    aPath.addClip()
    aPath.close()
    UIColor.green.set()
    aPath.stroke()

    //print("drawline")
    //print("Frompoint = ",fromPoint)
    //print("topoint = ",toPoint)

  /*  context?.setLineCap(.round)
    context?.setLineWidth(brushWidth)
    context?.setStrokeColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    context?.setBlendMode(.normal)

    context?.beginPath()
    context?.move(to: fromPoint)
    context?.addLine(to: toPoint)
    context?.closePath()
    context?.strokePath()*/


    //let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    fullview.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

As you can see, I tried it also with the context, but it wasn't working too.

Comment: [Check this](https://www.google.de/search?q=Drawing+a+line+in+Swift+3.x+with+UIBezierPath&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=4K5SWNHCAq2o8weUg52YDg)

Comment: Google is my friend :) i was just looking for the wrong keywords, thx

Comment: It is actually your exact title :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw a line with UIBezierPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662415/draw-a-line-with-uibezierpath)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use this to draw a line:

```
    let doYourPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight))
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = doYourPath.cgPath
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

Hope this help you out. This is just one the way to draw a line in swift.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are drawing into an image context (an offscreen bitmap), not into the view. That is quite likely not what you want? Make sure you have read [iOS Drawing Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html).

Your `UIView` subclass should probably just track the positions of the touches (like in a `var touchedPositions = [CGPoint]()`) and call `setNeedsDisplay()`.
Then implement the `func draw(_ rect: CGRect)` method in your subclass. Within this method, create your path and draw it according to the positions you tracked (w/o creating a new context).