# Swift add line above to control

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

In the below screen, I want to add horizontal line above to **"Item"** label and after **"Add"** button (below to the add button, I have dynamic table). `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` doesn't work here.

Can someone help me how to do this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is simple to add a subview to act as a line. For example:

Swift 4

```
var lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 320, height: 1.0))
lineView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
lineView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
self.view.addSubview(lineView)
```

Objective C

```
UIView * lineview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100,320,1)];
lineview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
lineview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
[self.view addSubview:lineview];
```

Or you can refer to this link to add CALayer or draw a view

[how do you draw a line programmatically from a view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846413/how-do-you-draw-a-line-programmatically-from-a-view-controller)

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve this in **Storyboard**.

All you have to do is drag a `UIView` with `height = 1` and `width` whatever is good for you (ideally equal to screen width). Place it where you want the lines to be.

Comment: Thanks. I like your answer

Comment: works. its easier than using CALayer etc... for newbies.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 3:

```
        let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0,
                                            y:  self.yourLabel.height - 1 ,
                                            width: self.yourLabel.frame.width,
                                            height: 1.4
                                           )
                             )

        lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.yourLabel.addSubview(lineView)
```