# UIBezierPath gives CGContextRestoreGState error

Tags: ios, objective-c

A simple line over a scrollview :

```
 UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(1382.0, 144.0)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(1655.0, 152.0)];
     path.lineWidth = 2;
    [path fill];
```

gives many of these :

```
CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

for:

```
CGContextSaveGState ,CGContextSetFlatness,CGContextAddPath,CGContextDrawPath
```

What is wrong with me ?

EDIT:
This also gives a crash:

```
   UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(1382.0, 144.0)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(1655.0, 152.0)];
    path.lineWidth = 2;

    CAShapeLayer *myLayer = (CAShapeLayer*) self.scroller.layer;
    UIBezierPath *testPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.bounds];
    [testPath appendPath:path];
    myLayer.path = testPath.CGPath;
    myLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    [self.scroller.layer addSublayer:myLayer];


[CALayer setPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: Can you check your scrollView frame when you set the bezier path ?

Comment: what you means by checking frame?

Comment: the point being drawing is inside its frame

Comment: that means you don't have a context, when you call the `–fill` method.

Comment: Thanks, i think i am missing the point, so what should i do about it?

Comment: Maybe your view frame is nul (well, (0,0,0,0)) when the path is added, because your error looks like an invalid context issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is saying that you cannot just call `fill`. That is intended to be used only within a valid context (e.g. in the `drawRect` of a `UIView` subclass or inside an image or PDF context). Either create a `UIView` subclass and implement this in its `drawRect` or create a `CAShapeLayer` and set its `path` property.

See [how do you draw a line programmatically from a view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846413/how-do-you-draw-a-line-programmatically-from-a-view-controller/16846770#16846770) for a discussion of these various approaches.

Comment: Your `CAShapeLayer *myLayer = (CAShapeLayer*) self.scroller.layer;` should be `CAShapeLayer *myLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];`. You want to create a `CAShapeLayer`, but your code was getting the existing `CALayer`.